# Detect when Spectrum color picker is open

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using Spectrum color picker.

I have this simple js to simulate clicking two other unrelated buttons

```
  document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
      send_dlg_optns();
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
      cancel_dlg();
    }
  }
```

Trouble is, if I hit escape or enter while the color picker is open, the color picker doesn't receive the keypress, and the other functions get called.
Is there a way to test for when the picker is open and maybe disable the onkeydown until the picker is closed?
tia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [show](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#events-show) and [hide](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#events-hide) events as described in the Spectrum docs to monitor when the picker is open or closed. You can then trigger your other keypress events conditionally only if the picker is hidden.

Something like this should do the trick:

HTML

```
<div class="picker" style="display: none;">
  <input type="text" id="showPaletteOnly"/>
</div>
<button class="open_picker">Open Picker</button>
```

JS

```
let isSpectrumOpen = false;  

$('#showPaletteOnly').spectrum({
  flat: false,
  color: '#008800',
  showInput: false,
  showButtons: false,
  preferredFormat: "hex",
  show: function(tinycolor) { changeSpectrumStatus() },
  hide: function(tinycolor) { changeSpectrumStatus() },
});

function changeSpectrumStatus() {
  isSpectrumOpen = !isSpectrumOpen;
  console.log(isSpectrumOpen);
}

$(".open_picker").on("click", function() {
  $(".picker").show();
})
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/x7umgbna/)

Comment: Thanks @Mar. I didn't need a button to activate it, but you showed me enough to test if open in my onkeydown.

Comment: I am very new to js. I see tinycolor defined as var = function(...) in spectrum.js. What is happening with show: function(tinycolor) { changeSpectrumStatus() }? I can guess (maybe not a good idea) that we are assigning changeSpectrumStatus() to show. Why the function(tinycolor) bit?

Comment: Tinycolor is simply the library Spectrum uses to parse colors - https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor